# right way to use if else in django template?

Tags: python, django

```
{% if {{result}} == 'Invalid' %}
 <span class="error-message-uname">Invalid .</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 11):

That depends on what version of Django you're using. [Since Django 1.2](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#smart-if-tag), this is valid:

```
{% if result == 'Invalid' %}
    <span class="error-message-uname">Invalid .</span>
{% endif %}
```

For earlier versions, use [`ifequal`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal):

```
{% ifequal result 'Invalid' %}
    <span class="error-message-uname">Invalid .</span>
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: That's fantastic. I've upgraded to django 1.2.3 a while back but didn't bother to look into all of the changes! Browsing stack is great : )

Comment: @Yuji - there's some great stuff in Django 1.2 - I'd definitely encourage you to take a look through the release notes.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if result == 'Invalid' %}
    <span class="error-message-uname">Invalid .</span>
{% endif %}
```

[See Django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#operator)

Comment: 'if' statement improperly formatted error i am getting.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936876/django-if-statement-improperly-formatted